# Control Template: "Content is set more than once"

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I'm trying to create a **Control Template** for button. I can add colors and text but not edit transitions of button because of this error:
`'System.Windows.Controls.Button.Content' property has already been set and can be set only once.`
But I set content once:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="redTitle" x:Key="redTitle">
        <!--Set to true to not get any properties from the themes.-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                    <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" BorderBrush="Red" Foreground="White">
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="States">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.01"></VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<VisualStateGroup>` element in `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>`.  The error is telling you that you assigned the button's content with both the `Content` attribute and implicitly by placing `<VisualStateGroup>` as the button's immediate child.  You meant to place the latter in a property setter.